# How to Play flash/swf type format videos in mobile browser?

Tags: html, angular6, video-streaming, red5, streaming-flv-video

I have been working with the project to play live streaming videos in mobile browser.
I have a swf/flash format to play in mobile browser. But mobile browsers not supporting flash. so how can i play these videos in mobile browser. Is there any way to do this?

Note: I am using Red5 sdk to play live streaming videos and it is wokring fine in Pc browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why there is a negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browsers do not support flash. And for good reason, it’s abandoned technology and a security problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I know mobile browsers don't support flash. Is there any way to play these kinds of formats in the mobile browser. Thanks

Comment: You are asking if you can play an swf without flash? The answer is no.

Comment: hmm. Anyway thanks, mate. I will look into some other.